# Send emails from gmail account using chrome extension(Oauth/SMTP)

Tags: oauth, google-chrome-extension, smtp, gmail, google-api

I have created an chrome extension for gmail which loads some data as gallery when user compose new mail.after selecting the data,data gets loaded into body and subject.

But when i want to send that mail from his/her account,i need to personalize the content and then send it.

I have used jason,js/jquery so far for doing all above stuff.

Now i am looking forward to sending part after personalization.

Thanks for stopping by...!!

Comment: How is this coming?  Did you get it working?

Comment: @JeffAxelrod: I used gmail smtp to send all the mails from users behalf. i tried using gmail api using auth. but combining both chrome extension and gmail api was difficult and throwing authentication errors. And everything is working perfectly and its live in chrome store.

Comment: Mind sharing the link?  Open source?

Comment: what part of code you want?? sending via smtp through code behind ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google doesn't want people messing with GMail code, so it is not publicly documented and obfuscated.  This is mainly a security issue, intended for prevent external code (such extensions) use GMail without user consent.

if you want to be present on GMail UI, you should do a gadget with [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/).

From Chrome extensions, it would be easier and safer using [Google Apps Scripts GMail Services API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_gmail?hl=es-ES).  You can send messages from there - but there's no UI interaction. You can start a GAS web service and call it from your extension via Ajax.  Using [Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_content?hl=es-ES) is the simplest way to do it.

You should provide a way to users accept (one time only) running that service in their behalf, so the service can access their private GMail data.  Simply navigate to the content service's url, Google will prompt them.

Comment: @YoArgentina:Thanks for reply....i have registered my app at google api.i am getting access token when i request for general scope(getting data).but i don't know how to proceed further for SMTP from there.

I'm referring to [oauth protocol smtp](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_protocol#smtp) and [Xoauth2_protocol](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_protocol)

Comment: Ok, that's a different aproach.  Mine doesn't need OAuth nor any authentication protocol.  Your Google Apps Script can send messages from your GMail account.  If you publish it (not as a service), the script will use the user's GMail account.  Google will ask him once for permission.

Comment: i didnt know that was possible, could you explain more in steps. Like how does google permission works. how do i get users email. i dont know really what i am asking but i guess you will understand what i wanted to know. ;D

Comment: Question: how do you send data from extension to script? Very confused

Comment: as far as i can tell GAS web app runs as a page. How would you make it into extension.

Comment: Yes, GAS runs as a page, or at least you invoque it by calling an url.  You can also access via JSONP, read more here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/content_service?hl=es-ES